# Connecting Two Items in a Database - Best method?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-design

In a MySQL Database, I have two tables: Users and Items

The idea is that Users can create as many Items as they want, each with unique IDs, and they will be connected so that I can display all of the Items from a particular user.

Which is the better method in terms of performance and clarity? Is there even a real difference?

1. Each User will contain a column with a list of Item IDs, and the query will retrieve all matching Item rows.
2. Each Item will contain a column with the User's ID that created it, and the query will call for all Items with a specific User ID.

Comment: 2nd approach is better because it defines one-to-many relationship and it also defines that you have to create two tables (user & item) and uou can easily join both tables and index also be used for that query

Comment: 'KISS' (Keep It Simple,Stupid) it. This is a typical one-to-many relationship, 2nd approach will solve it.

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2nd approach is better**, because it defines `one-to-many` relationship on `USER` to `ITEM` table.

You can create foreign key on `ITEM` table on `USERID` columns which refers to `USERID` column in `USER` table.

You can easily join both tables and index also be used for that query.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just clarify why approach 2 is superior...

The approach 1 means you'd be packing several distinct pieces of information within the same database field. That violates the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore the [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). As a consequence:

- Indexing won't work (bad for performance).
- [FOREIGN KEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)s and type safety won't work (bad for data integrity).

Indeed, the approach 2 is the standard way for representing such "one to many" relationship.

Comment: @BasilBourque You have linked "1NF" and "FOREIGN KEYs" to some YouTube video about Jesus Christ. What's up with that??

Comment: Sorry about my incorrect links. That will be the last time I try to do an edit on an iPhone. I have now installed correct links to Wikipedia articles for background info.

Answer (score 1):

As long as an item doesn't have multiple owners it's a [one to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many) relationship. This typically gets reduced to the second approach you mention, eg. have a `user` or `created_by` column in the `Items` table.

Answer (score 1):

If a User can have one or more Items but each Item is owned by only a single User, then you have a classic One-To-Many relationship.

The first option, cramming a list of related IDs into a single field, is exactly the wrong way to do it.

Assign a unique identifier field to each table (called the primary key). And add an extra field to the Item table, a foreign key, the id of the User that owns that item.

Like this ERD ([entity-relationship diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow.27s_Foot_Notation.))…

[image: Diagram of two tables, parent table user_ and child table item_]

You have some learning to do about [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) design and [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).